# Postgres string to array and check if includes value

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, select

I have got a table `employer_entity` with column `tokens`. This column is a `varchar` and it contains many tokens splitted by comma, for instance:

```
id | tokens
---|------------------
 1 | aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc
```

Now I want to build a query that will check if `tokens` column contains the token `aaaaa`.
Here is what I've got

```
select *
from employer_entity
where 'aaaaa'
in (string_to_array(employer_entity.tokens, ','))
```

But it throws an error

```
Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `any` operator, not the `in` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   employer_entity
WHERE  'aaaaa' = ANY(STRING_TO_ARRAY(employer_entity.tokens, ','))
```

Comment: `SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function string_to_array(text[], unknown) does not exist`